# Questions about Mr.speaker's retirement

Tags: meaning-in-context

As we come to    **the end of**    what must be **the longest retirement** since Frank Sinatra Mr.Speaker, I'm sure the whole House will want to join me in thanking you and hoping that you enjoy in your retirement the soothing medicament that you have so often prescribed for the rest of us, he added.

1. Why do they say "the end of Mr.speaker's retirement"? It's just started.
2. What's the medicament that he often prescribes to MPs?

Comment: It's a joke. Frank Sinatra was always retiring and then going back on stage and singing again.  You could have looked this up: https://www.allmusic.com/artist/frank-sinatra-mn0000792507/biography As for the "medicament", that requires knowing a bit more these MPs than I do.

Comment: I assume "the soothing medicament" is an oblique reference to ***Order**!* As stereotypically called for by the Speaker himself during heated parliamentary debates, but *in this exact context* with the additional allusion to ***peace, tranquility***. The MP who actually said those words probably intended them to be understood as implying he'd be happy to see the Speaker metaphorically "laid to rest" somewhere well away from the political circus of Westminster (where many MPs have been trying to get rid of him for years, because of his partisan approach to the job, particularly re Brexit).

Comment: ...I just discovered it was actually the ***PM*** (not just "an MP") who delivered this "back-handed compliment". (He probably got it from a sharp-witted speech-writer though! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Mr Bercow has on several occasions advised over-excited Members he has difficulty calling to order to take a "soothing medicament" -- that is, a tranquillizer.

Comment: @StoneyB: I didn't know that. I find the man so irritating I try to avoid listening to him!

Comment: imho, if the Speaker "talks down" to MPs, that inevitably raises passions and encourages them to "play up". Bercow's characteristic style therefore undermines the very *purpose* of the office (he probably knows that perfectly well, but doesn't care because he's more interested in promoting *himself* than assisting the business of the institution). Anyway, that's enough politics from me.